# Wrong path for statics when Dynamic routing a template Bottle

Tags: python, dynamic, routes, bottle

i'm working with bottle framework and i found this problem.

When i used static path everything works fine, but when i used dynamic routing the path for .css and .js change and give not file found error.

I have this method:

```
@get('/mod_user/<id_user>')
def mod_user(id_user):
    user = driver.get_user_by_id(id_user)
    return template('moduser', user=user)
```

And i have this one for static files, which works fine for path like '/contact', etc:

```
@route('/static/:path#.+#', name='static')
def static(path):
    return static_file(path, root='static')
```

the problem come beacuse add /mod_user to the path for search static:

```
http://10.141.0.63:8080/mod_user/static/css/formularioadd.css
```

I tried changing path for static in several ways and nothing works.

Some idea?

thank you all

Comment: I answer myself, to avoid this problem you have to be sure that your statics files has absolute path if you are extending all from a principal template.

Answer (score 0):

You have no route that matches `/mod_user/static`.

(Also, you're needlessly using a regex.)

Have you tried something like this?

```
@route('/mod_user/static/<path:path>')
def static(path):
    ...
```

Comment: yes, i solved, the problem was that you have to put the css file absolute in the general template. ty anyway